# Banshee hangs on the "import" dialog

Tags: 11.10, banshee, freeze

I tried to import some .mp3 files from a memory stick into Banshee on my netbook.  I tried several times but each time, as soon as I opened the Import dialog, Banshee hung.  I waited several minutes and still nothing.  I looked in `top` and Banshee was using 100% CPU.

I finally resorted to installing Rhythmbox and it worked fine.  Any ideas on what happened with Banshee?

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, thanks! [Instructions here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).